# Is there a way to download Android apps to my PC?

Tags: download, android

I want to download an Android app to look at what's inside, but I don't own an Android phone. Is there a way to download the file (I'm not sure of the name, on iPhone it's a .ipa) using just a PC?

Comment: I think Android application install files use the *.apk* extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android apps are packaged as .apk files. Usually you would download them direct to the phone via Android Market, but you can Google for .apk files (or torrents of .apk files). You probably should make sure the app you're getting is a free one.

Comment: It's a free app. No links googling for it though. I wonder if there's a way to spoof the android market.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download an application just to *look at what's inside* I'm assuming you don't mind if it's a free application.

[Android Freeware Directory](http://www.androidfreeware.org/) - Choose an application and click the download link at the bottom of it's page.

(As mentioned in my comment on the question; it's a *.apk* file)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The app I'm looking for is a free app, but that directory doesn't have it.

Answer (score -3):

Copied from this page: [TOP 10 website list for downloading Android Mod Apps & Games:](https://medium.com/@johirulislam_84090/you-should-know-about-top-05-website-for-downloading-android-mod-apps-games-edd650275c94)

1. http://www.PreenSoft.com

   One of the most quality and famous site in the world for android Application and games. This site have lots of android application and games, which are regularly updated. PreenSoft.com provide without ads, spyware, spam, adware web experience for mobile and computer user. Also it provides hassle free direct downloading links, daily latest instant updated mod/crack/premium apps according play store. This site Don’t use link shorter. Provide requested apps and games with is short time. That’s why PreenSoft.com is a best and 1st position website in the world.

   After clicking through 4 or 5 pages, then waiting for a download timer, you might find some .apk files to download
2. https://www.revdl.com/

   This is another good site. Because Provide direct downloading links, provide daily latest instant updated mod/crack/premium apps according play store. Its use ads, spyware, spam, adware. That’s why revdl.com is 2nd position website in the world.
3. http://iHackedit.com

   It's use ads, spyware, spam, adware. That’s why apklevel. com is 4th position website in the world.

   Takes 5 or 6 pages to click through, then wait a while, then enter a code, then finally download an .apk file.